# forward foreign exchange rates

Tags: foreign-exchange, market-data, historical-data

Is there anywhere online I can lookup forward rates for foreign exchange? Preferably this would include historic rates too.

Comment: I'm afraid future foreign exchange rates are no more known than future stock prices.

Comment: @C. Ross: He's likely referring to getting quotes on **FX futures**, which are forward contracts, i.e. contracts to settle an exchange of currency at a date in the future.

Comment: The forward rate is the price you can agree now, for an exchange sometime in the future.

Comment: Here's a good definition of FX currency forward contracts and futures contracts: http://fxconsulting.oanda.com/discover/hedging-products

Comment: Would they be equivalent to options on something holding that currency pair? http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=NYSE:FXY

Comment: @Ganesh, @Chris Thanks!  I figured there was something I was missing.

Comment: James: no, an option is more valuable than a forward or future for the same rate because you can choose not to exercise if the exchange rate swings against you.

Comment: Closing my own old question as off-topic because it is under the current rules of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few searches on Google revealed a few sites:

- [the Wall Street Journal](http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3023-fut_currency-futures.html?mod=mdc_curr_pglnk) (okay, I didn't Google for that one, I just guessed)
- [quotes.ino.com](http://quotes.ino.com/exchanges/futboard/#currencies)
- [barchart.com](http://www.barchart.com/futures/)

I think that any trading platform willing to let you trade futures will also let you see the current prices (e.g. E*Trade). You can probably find others.

Comment: Thanks! For some silly reason it didn't occur to me to google for futures prices instead of forwards prices.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [list of cross currency pairs futures](https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductGroupHierarchy.shtml?groupDetail=&group.groupId=16) offered by Intercontinental Exchange ("Ice").  They show existing future contracts for the given currency pairs.

It's not exactly what you were looking for, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use http://oanda.com when I'm looking for forex data.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a really good site I've not seen before

Answer (score -1):

Use Google search, e.g.,

```
1 cad = ? usd
1 usd = ? jpy
1 usd = ? eur

or you can spell out

1 canadian dollar = ? us dollar
1 us dollar = ? japanese yen
1 us dollar = ? euros
```

Another good website with 30-day or 120-day historical data is [x-rates.com](http://www.x-rates.com/d/CAD/USD/graph120.html), you can select base currency and exchanged currency.

Comment: This gives the rates for making the exchange right now, as opposed to the rate I can agree now to make the exchange at some point in the future.